# Trying to find a word from loose pronunciation?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic

Would it be allowed to ask if a word exist which would loosely correspond to an IPA? Would such a question be on-topic, or off-topic?

For example,

> Is there a word or combination of words that would be a loose
>   homophone to /ædhɒk/?

Answer would be *ad hoc* or *haddock*.

Comment: Interesting question. I wouldn't say such questions are off-topic in general, but I wouldn't want this site to degenerate into a (yet another) collection of mondegreens, either.

Comment: @RegDwight: I've been thinking about it, and maybe it would categorized as ["too localized"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/new-question-migration-paths/) in most of the case.

Comment: I'm somewhat confused what the purpose of the question is.  Why would [hædək] be homophonous in any meaningful way with [ædhɒk]?  They don't even loosely rhyme.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: When I mean loose, I really mean loose, I am not searching identical sounds but more similar. And I have to admit I am mostly thinking in french where _haddock_ is /a.dɔk/ and _ad hoc_ /a.d‿ɔk/. Let's say I was searching some kind of word play, in order to name one of my project, but inbetween I decided against asking the actual question on EL&U.

Comment: Off-topic comment, maybe, but how does one insert special characters in Markdown, such as the phonetic symbols I see here?

Comment: Actually, just found the question that specifically deals with this. I guess there's no "native" way to do it here. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see how such a question could be considered off-topic. It would be like a single-word-request, except the starting point is a pronunciation instead of a definition.

Comment: Didn't thought about the `single-word-request` tag. Thanks!